# How to install dbus-python on macOS?

Tags: python, macos, dbus

In the first step: configure, I got the following error:

```
... ... 
checking for DBUS... no
configure: error: Package requirements (dbus-1 >= 1.6) were not met:

No package 'dbus-1' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables DBUS_CFLAGS
and DBUS_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Answer (score 5):

OSX is complaining that it can't find dbus in the system. Try installing it first by doing something like:

```
brew install dbus
```

Then, try installing `dbus-python` by running

```
pip install dbus-python
```

In order to run the dbus daemon do `brew services start dbus` as said in the [documentation](https://github.com/zbentley/dbus-osx-examples/blob/master/installation/README.md#session-bus).

Comment: Didn't work for me. The error is [here](https://pastebin.com/TwLx8fXq)

Comment: did not work for me either I am on a mac M1 chip mac book pro 13"