# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbus'" on macOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, dbus

I'm getting an error when I'm using the notify2 module.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dbus'

The error is from the notify2.py file.

When I tried `pip install dbus` this was the output:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement dbus (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for dbus
```

When I tried `brew install python-dbus`:

```
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "python-dbus".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

I couldn't find any answers related to macOS to fix this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install dbus-python on macOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43136067/how-to-install-dbus-python-on-macos)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try doing `pip install dbus-python`. It worked for me on fedora 34.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about MacOS, but debian-based OS I got issue resolved w:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install libglib2.0-dev libdbus-1-3 libdbus-1-dev
```

As per this [so](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1325906/modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-dbus-bindings)